# I want to learn twitter bootstrap.Which is the best site for learning online?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How much time is required to learn bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the official website [www.getbootstrap.com](http://www.getboostrap.com)

Go through the Getting Started section, it will cover all the main things to know about using this amazing framework.

After that, just try to build a simple website using the responsive grids and available components.